# Summation Simplification

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, proof-writing

> **Problem:** Let $x$ be a real number. Suppose $x\ne 1$. Let $\in\Bbb N$. Find a simpler expression for the sum
>
> $$U=\sum_{k=1}^nk^2x^k\;.$$
>
> For your final answer, put everything over a common denominator and in the resulting numerator, collect like powers of $x$.

Here's my attempt at it:

$$\begin{align*}
U&=1+x+2^2x^2+\ldots+(n-1)^2x^{n-1}\\
U&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^2x^k
\end{align*}$$

Hence $$xU=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^2x^{(k+1)}\;.$$

As $k$ goes from $0$ to $n-1$, $k+1$ goes from $1$ to $n$, so the last sum can be rewritten as $$xU=\sum_{k=1}^nk^2x^{(k)}\;.$$ Thus $$U=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^2x^{(k)}$$ and

$$xU=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^2x^{(k)}+(n^2)x^n\;.$$

So $U-xU=1-(n^2)x^n$.

In other words, $(1-x)U1-(n^2)x^n$.

Now $1-x\ne 0$ because $x\ne 1$.

Therefore $$U=\frac{\big(1-(n^2)x^n\big)}{(1-x)}\;.$$

I got to a reasonable seeming answer, but I can't help but feel I messed something up.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you changed $U$ at the very beginning: it was given to you as

$$U=\sum_{k=1}^nk^2x^k\;,$$

and you changed it to $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^2x^k\;,$$ thereby dividing it by $x$. Your $xU$ therefore should have been

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2x^{k+1}\;.$$

At this point you wanted to shift the index to get $x^k$, but you didn’t do it quite right. When in doubt, introduce a new name for the shifted index; here I’ll let $\ell=k+1$, so that $k=\ell-1$. Then

$$xU=\sum_{k=1}^nk^2x^{k+1}=\sum_{\ell=2}^{n+1}(\ell-1)^2x^\ell\;,$$

and when we rename $\ell$ back to $k$, we have

$$xU=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}(k-1)^2x^k\;.$$

To continue along the lines that I think you had in mind, this is

$$xU=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}k^2x^k-2\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}kx^k+\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}x^k\;.\tag{1}$$

Now

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}k^2x^k=U+(n+1)^2x^{n+1}-x\;,$$

so $(1)$ can be reduced to

$$(x-1)U=(n+1)^2x^{n+1}-x-2\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}kx^k+\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}x^k\;.$$

The last summation is just a finite geometric series, so rewriting it in closed form shouldn’t be a problem. It’s possible that you’ve already found a closed form for $\sum kx^k$ as well in working up to this exercise; if so, you can just use it. Otherwise you’ll have to solve that problem as well; you can use basically the same technique that you tried here. (There are also other ways to do it. For instance, you can observe that

$$\sum_{k=1}^nkx^k=x\sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k-1}=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx^k\right)$$

and replace the geometric series in the parentheses with a closed form for it.)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Brian M. Scott wrote at the end of his answer, you could do the following for a slightly more complex problem $$V=\sum_{k=1}^nk^3x^k$$ writing that $$k^3=Ak(k-1)(k-2)+Bk(k-1)+Ck=k (2 A-B+C)+k^2 (B-3 A)+A k^3$$ So, identifying the doefficients of the different powers $A=1$,$B=3A=3$,$C=B-2A=1$. So $$V=x^3\sum_{k=1}^nk(k-1)(k-2)x^{k-3}+3x^2\sum_{k=1}^nk(k-1)x^{k-2}+x\sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k-1}$$ $$V=x^3\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^nx^{k}\Big)+3x^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^nx^{k}\Big)+x\frac{d}{dx}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^nx^{k}\Big)$$ and now, take into account that $$\sum_{k=1}^nx^{k}=\frac{x \left(x^n-1\right)}{x-1}$$ Compute the three derivatives and simplify; for this case, hoping I did not make any mistake, the final result should be $$\frac{x \left(n^3 x^{n+3}+\left(3 n^3+6 n^2-4\right) x^{n+1}-\left(3 n^3+3 n^2-3
   n+1\right) x^{n+2}-(n+1)^3 x^n+x^2+4 x+1\right)}{(1-x)^4}$$ For sure, your problem is simpler but the same approach applies.